# Calculate minute differences in a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working with Power BI. I wanna know from the Datestamp column see how much minute difference it's between the previous value and the last one.
I tried this formula below but got totally different value.

```
Datediff = 
DATEDIFF(
     DataView[CommTimestamp];
     TODAY();
     minute
)
```

The date-stamp column look like `YYYY-MM-DD-HOUR-MINUTE-SECOND`

Comment: First of all check your column data type and make sure it's date type. If that's not  the case, Please provide sample data, your result and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written compares the `[CommTimestamp]` column with the `TODAY()` function. `TODAY()` returns `YYYY-MM-DD-00:00:00` when it's calculated (different for Calculated columns and measures).

Therefore what you will see is the number of minutes from `[dateTime]` until today:

[image]

NB. That the `[DiffAdd]` column which is calculated like: `[DateTime]+[DateDiffToday]/1440` doesn't take the seconds into account.

So without more info about your data table and your expected results, it's difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know difference in minutes you cannot use `TODAY()` as Oscar stated, it only provides 'Day' grannularity. You ca try using `NOW()` instead:

```
Datediff = 
DATEDIFF(
     DataView[CommTimestamp];
     NOW();
     minute
)
```